# Convergence of the solution of Volterra integral equation with convergent kernel (reposted, need help!)

Tags: integral-transforms, limits-and-convergence, continuity, integral-operators, integral-kernel

Consider the following Volterra integral equation

$g(t)=∫_0^tK_n(t,s)w_n(s)ds$

where $g(t)$ and $K_n(t,s)$ are continuous and $K_n(t,s)≥K_{n+1}(t,s)$ for all $t,s$. Moreover, $K_n(t,s)$ converges to $K(t,s)$.

The conditions of $K_n(t,s)$ are as follows :

--> $Kn(t,s)\neq 0$ for each $n$ and for all $t,s$.

--> $\frac{\partial K_n(t,s)}{\partial t}$ is continuous.

--> $K(t,s)\neq 0$ for all $t,s$.

Conditions 1, 2 are sufficient to gurantee the existence of solution $w_n(s)$.

Then, can we say that the solution $w_n(s)$ also converges to some function $w(s)$?

If so, how can i prove it?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1079644/convergence-of-the-solution-of-volterra-integral-equation-with-convergent-kernel

Comment: And there has been never an answer there.. So maybe today is a luckier day? I really would like to know this... thank you!